# Next Leaguecraft ggClassic presented by Arqade - play, ask, answer and win prizes!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion

**This contest has officially ended.** Congratulations to our winners! They are as follows (*drumroll...*):

The **5 winners of the $25 League of Legends game cards** are:

- [ponsfonze](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/29452/ponsfonze)
- [monocledsardine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/29688/monocledsardine)
- [Fluttershy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/14775/fluttershy)
- [Coldewe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/29591/coldewe)
- [Rapida](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3015/rapida)

And our lucky **Grand Prize Winner**, receiving the graphics card of his choice, is [timlan](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/29344/timlan)!

A lot of great questions and answers came out of this contest, and I hope it was fun for everyone, especially our new users who came over from the ggClassic. Thanks to everyone who participated! If you are one of our winners, you will be contacted shortly via email.

---

**Edit**: To allow for questions during the tournament replays next week, the deadline for contest submissions has been extended until Wednesday, 7/25 at 11:59 pm UTC.

[image]

The [Next Leaguecraft ggClassic](http://ggchronicle.com/announcing-next-leaguecraft-ggclassic-presented-arqade-july-14-15-21-22/) kicks off on July 14th, and we’re the title sponsor! To help the pros as they do battle, and make spectating a little more fun, we’re holding a contest to see who can ask and answer the best [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) questions on Arqade.

**To enter:** simple! [Play League of Legends](https://signup.leagueoflegends.com/en/signup/index), and whenever you have a question about it, [ask it on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=league-of-legends). If you see another question you know the answer to, share your knowledge by answering it!

Entering the contest is easy, but giving yourself a fighting chance at winning is the real challenge. Arqade is all about quality and helping you find the best way to win that match. So, only great posts will be eligible for prizes. See below for tips to make your post great!

**The Rules:**

- The contest will run for the duration of the Next Leaguecraft ggClassic, from July 14th to July 22nd. Only questions and answers posted between July 14th at 12:01 am UTC and July 25th at 11:59 pm UTC will be eligible for the contest.
- All questions must be related to League of Legends. Make sure you tag it [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) or it won’t count for the contest.
- Only answers to questions tagged [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) will count for the contest.
- Only questions and answers with a score of 5 or more will be eligible for prizes.
- Each post you make that has a score of 5 or more when the contest ends gets you one entry into a raffle for prizes. However, each post that is closed or has a negative score when the contest ends will subtract one of your entries. So make sure that what you post is good!

**What makes a good question or answer?**

First of all, Arqade is not a forum. Arqade is for specific, practical Q&A. If you want to chat about something, awesome - we have a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/35/the-bridge) for that! But don’t just post a discussion thread as a question - it will get closed and you’ll lose raffle entries.

Generally, anything related to gameplay is **on topic**. That includes (but of course isn’t limited to!) things like:

- Strategy
- Puzzle solving
- Game mechanics and terminology
- Plot and characters in games
- Game-specific hardware

Some examples of things that are **off topic** include:

- Game development
- Game identification
- Shopping advice
- Piracy

For more info, check out our [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq).

Before you post a question, try to make sure it fits within the scope of the site and hasn’t been asked before. If you ask a good question, people will vote it up. If you provide a helpful answer, people will vote that up too. However, posts that don’t fit within the scope of the site will be voted down or closed, and you will lose entries.

**The Prizes:** On to the good part!

- How to win: Every League of Legends post you make (question or answer) that ends the contest with a score of 5 or more will get you one entry into a raffle for prizes.
- **One lucky Grand Prize winner will receive a graphics card of his/her choice, worth up to $250!**
- We're also giving away $25 League of Legends Game Cards to five First Prize winners!

[image: graphics card]   [image: Game Card]

Lots of chances to win, so play, ask, answer and get excited!

Comment: +1 for `What makes a good question or answer`

Comment: Unrelated, are closed questions eligible for prizes? Hopefully it won't come up, but it might affect duped questions.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: `However, each post that is closed or has a negative score when the contest ends will subtract one of your entries.`

Comment: I think rule 5 (-1 for closed entries) is a bit harsh, as duplicates are also considered [closed] and depending on the wording it is really hard to make sure the question is not a double post.

Comment: I think dupes should not subtract a point -- dupes are not inherently bad

Comment: @Wipqozn Oh, *every* place is a raffle? I see.

Comment: @ayckoster it will encourage people to search before posting, so it will help prevent duplicates - which is good considering that last time we got a lot of duplicates.

Comment: @Oak, IMO, they should count as 0 (not +1 nor -1) -- otherwise we'll get a lot of requests for deleting them, which is not good.

Comment: +1 for the explanation! The "off topic" section could use an item about questions that are some variant of "I would like to participate in a discussion about ______" ([FAQ#dontask]), which was one of the more common close reasons during the last contest.

Comment: @JQAn There was some [discussion about this in chat already.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5326263#5326263).

Comment: @wipq, I'm way late to the party, but the first sentence I see in that link is that we should close the original if a better written dupe question comes along? That is so not how this work that it scares me that it's even suggested.

Comment: Why does League not deserve a cool site skin like D3 did?

Comment: @Ender Do you want an actual answer or a cynical answer? :P

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh both, why not? I was a smart alec enough to ask the question lol.

Comment: @Ender Well, I don't have a real answer, but my cynical answer is that only bad games get a site theme dedicated to them (Diablo 3, Mass Effect). :P

Comment: @Ender I would guess it's some function of how popular (in pageviews, etc.) they expect the contest to be, and how much spare time Jin has at the moment. Whether or not you like D3 or Mass Effect, hyped-up new releases generate big, permanent traffic bumps for the site that these tourny-related contests have a hard time matching.

Comment: As an incentive to get users to post better questions and answers, why not reward the top question and answer (overall), at the end the promotion, with an extra entry each?

Comment: @QAzer we've done contests based on top voted Q&A before, but the worry is that it leads to spam voting. This way, all the posts that meet a minimum threshold get an equal shot, so there's an incentive to make your post good, but not solicit spam votes.

Comment: @Lauren - I do like this approach - although for bigger contests I think some mix of the two, like how the D3 one worked, is probably best.  It's fine for this, though.  (And anything to potentially improve the quality of the traffic we've gotten from these...I realize it's good visibility for the site but these LoL tournaments haven't gotten us good posters or significantly increased traffic so I am unconvinced of their value...)

Comment: Nice to see the grand prize go to a new LoL user!  And one with several upvoted answers too.

Comment: Nice! monocledsardine really deserves a prize for the work he put into answering [Which walls are Flashable?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/77821/20893)

Comment: @BBz That's what exceptional bounties are for. :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that ended a long time ago.